# error in Fragment while try using findViewById

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, findviewbyid, bottomnavigationview

I get an error when I use `findViewById` in `Fragment`.

How can I solve it?

```
public class Discover extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "Discover";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_discover, container, false);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: starting.");
    setupBottomNavigationView();
    return root;
}

private void setupBottomNavigationView(){

    Log.d(TAG, "setupBottomNavigationView: setting up BottomNavigationView");
    BottomNavigationViewEx bottomNavigationViewEx = (BottomNavigationViewEx) findViewById(R.id.bottomNavViewBar);
    BottomNavigationViewHelper.setupBottomNavigationView(bottomNavigationViewEx);

}

public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    // Set title bar
    ((LandingPage) getActivity())
            .setActionBarTitle("Discover Photos");

   }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the root view for using `findViewById`:

Assuming this view `id.bottomNavViewBar` exist in this layout `layout.fragment_discover`or included:

```
public class Discover extends Fragment {
View root;

private static final String TAG = "Discover";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_discover, container, false);
Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: starting.");
setupBottomNavigationView();
return root;
}

private void setupBottomNavigationView(){
Log.d(TAG, "setupBottomNavigationView: setting up BottomNavigationView");
BottomNavigationViewEx bottomNavigationViewEx = (BottomNavigationViewEx) root.findViewById(R.id.bottomNavViewBar);
BottomNavigationViewHelper.setupBottomNavigationView(bottomNavigationViewEx);

}

public void onResume(){
super.onResume();

// Set title bar
((LandingPage) getActivity())
        .setActionBarTitle("Discover Photos");

    }

  }
}
```

Now whenever you need to use `findViewById`, you can use the `root` view like this:

```
root.findViewById(R.id.yourview)
```

Comment: Thanks alot. This is helpful

Comment: Glad I could help, And don't forget to accept one of the answers if it solved your problem.